# What is the api rate limit of AWS IAM sts assume role?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am looking for the official documentation on the service quota of the api rate limit for IAM sts assume role api calls.

Bard says its 500 per second which seems correct but need the official doc which I cannot locate.

Please help me find it.